# How to correctly provide a static xml resource and bind a combobox?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, data-binding

Good day everyone!

I have a problem binding a static xml resource to a combobox in a C# WPF application. It basically works, but always fills (a correct amount of) items with the first entry in my xml file.
Please have a look at my code:

XML file (*resources/config/xml/ServiceProviders.xml*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ServiceProviders xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ServiceProvider name="Service Provider 1">
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider name="Service Provider 2">
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider name="Service Provider 3">
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider name="Service Provider 4">
    </ServiceProvider>
    <ServiceProvider name="Service Provider 5">
    </ServiceProvider>
</ServiceProviders>
```

The XAML code including the binding (just a `Grid` in the main window):

```
<Grid Name="ServiceProviderGrid" 
            Grid.Row="0" 
            Grid.Column="0" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Name="ServiceProviderData" 
                         Source="resources/config/xml/ServiceProviders.xml" 
                         XPath="/ServiceProviders/ServiceProvider">
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ServiceProviderDataTemplate">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=/ServiceProviders/ServiceProvider/@name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Name="ServiceProviderLabel" 
           Grid.Row="0" 
           Margin="10,10,10,5" 
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
           Service Provider
    </Label>
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ServiceProviderDataTemplate}"
              Name="ServiceProviderComboBox"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              Visibility="Visible"
              Grid.Row="1" 
              Margin="10,5,10,10" 
              VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
              SelectedIndex="1" 
              Cursor="Hand">
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

The problem I am facing is best illustrated in the following image:

[image: ComboBox fills all items with first value]

Does anyone know how to fill the `ComboBox` with all the different entries provided in the static xml resource?
The purpose is a data resource that may be edited by users in future. They are to be able to create, edit and remove service providers. But at first, all of the providers have to be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have already selected the Service Provider in your DataContext so you should only specify the property that you wish to display in the ItemTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ServiceProviderDataTemplate">
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@name}"></TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did it!